# Load Runner Connection time out

Tags: wpf, wcf, loadrunner, connection-timeout

Our performance testing team is running test on our WPF-WCF-Sql Server application and they are facing connection timeout after the load goes above 75 users

Error -27796: Failed to connect to server "81.171.180.119:4567": [10060] Connection timed out

I would like to know what can be steps to look at bottlenecks which may be causing issues like maybe some setting in Load Runner or identify the code bottlenecks.

Thanks

Comment: Use SiteScope on your server. There is a SiteScope license that comes with LR so you don't need to buy anything.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote my first guess would be a configuration on the server that only allows 75 active sessions to connect to it. I would start by looking into the server's configuration for concurrent threads/sessions/connections.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the runtime settings in load runner{press F4} , in miscellaneous >options and change connection timeout to around 240 seconds depending how your application is responding.

now loadrunner will wait for about 4 minutes until response is received.

Check similar settings for step download timeout in case of downloads are there in your application.